# My React app sees my JSON data as a collection of data

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, fetch

I have a simple fetch which returns this data:

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "username": "Mr.T",
  "cash": 994999.9,
  "portfolio": [
    {
      "id": 874,
      "stock": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "symbol": "AAPL"
      },
      "purchasePrice": 119.05,
      "quantity": 42,
      "purchaseDate": "2020-12-01T09:12:32.591+00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "stock": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "symbol": "AAPL"
      },
      "purchasePrice": 170.23,
      "quantity": 200,
      "purchaseDate": "2020-12-01T09:12:22.975+00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "stock": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "symbol": "AAPL"
      },
      "purchasePrice": 150.23,
      "quantity": 100,
      "purchaseDate": "2020-12-01T09:12:22.932+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "offers": [
    
  ],
  "stockPerformanceList": [
    {
      "id": 879,
      "stock": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "symbol": "AAPL"
      },
      "stockTotalAmount": 342,
      "averagePurchasePrice": 158.1,
      "totalPurchaseValue": 54069.1,
      "stockCurrentPrice": 119.05,
      "stockCurrentValue": 40715.1,
      "stockValueChange": -0.25
    }
  ],
  "portfolioPerformance": {
    "id": 9,
    "portfolioTotalValue": 1035715.0,
    "portfolioTotalStockValue": 40715.1,
    "percentageStockValue": 0.04,
    "percentageCashValue": 0.96
  }
}
```

As you can see it's a simple object, here is my code snippet:

```
  const [MyData, setMyData] = useState({});

  const FetchData = async () =>{
    const resp = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/user/getuseraccount");
    console.log(resp.data);
    setMyData(resp.data);
  }
```

The console log shows my data fine, but I get this error at setting the state:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, stock, stockTotalAmount, averagePurchasePrice, totalPurchaseValue, stockCurrentPrice, stockCurrentValue, stockValueChange}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Any idea why?

It seemed to work for some time, but maybe I screwed something up, if you need more info, please let me know and I edit this post

Comment: That looks more like an error one would see when trying to render objects instead of JSX. Can you provide a more complete code example? You look to be attempting to render `MyData.stockPerformanceList` directly somewhere.

Comment: Include your html implementation

Comment: @DrewReese sure, but at least 5 components are using this data, the others can use it without problem.

I have a quick question. Is it better to fetch the data once and pass it to child components, or do the fetch every time the components are rendered?

Comment: It only takes one component not handling/rendering data correctly. Surely the error has a component/file/line number associated with it. If you're in the browser there is probably a link to the line in the console. I would say fetching once is better than fetching every time everywhere, but depending on the data use case you may need to *always* fetch latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mazen Sharkawy said, you can't render objects

I'm new to react but I think people tend to 'deconstruct' the object first

```
const {dataproperty1, dataproperty2, .... datapropertyX} = data;
```

this was you can just return

```
return (
         <> 
         <div key ={id} > 
        // pick a unique property to help react 
        //differenciate between the instances

        <p>{dataproperty1}</p>

        </div

         </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to render an object which is not allowed

```
<p>{data}</p> //not allowed
```

However if you want to print an object for some reason, you can try the following

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p> //allowed
```

But what you probably wanna do is use the data inside the object individually, for example:

```
<p>Username {data.username}</p>
```